# Insert into one table2 from table1 get the id and then insert into table3 SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across a situation where

1. I need to insert multiple rows of data from a table1 into table2
2. With each row insert into table2, I need to get the scope ID and insert that with more data into table3

I have come up with something like below, but it appears it keeps inserting the same scope id over and over into table3.

```
insert into dbo.table2(name_client, phone_client)
SELECT name_client, phone_client
from dbo.table1 where name_client is not null

declare @clientID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into dbo.table3(......, client_id)
SELECT ......., @clientID from table1 --where some condition
```

Comment: `@clientID` can only hold a single value, it doesn't hold a list. And `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` can only obtain a single value. I think you want the [OUTPUT CLAUSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I do not have a join from table1 to table3 how is it possible? @DaleK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OUTPUT clause to get the inserted identity values to table variable. Use the table variable to insert into the third table.

Sample code is given below:

```sql
-- Declare table variable
DECLARE @tableName Table(ClientId INT,name_client VARCHAR(25), 
phone_client VARCHAR(25))

--Use OUTPUT clause to get results into table variable
insert into dbo.table2(name_client, phone_client)
OUTPUT inserted.ClientId, inserted.name_client, inserted.phone_client INTO @tableName
SELECT name_client, phone_client
from dbo.table1 where name_client is not null;

--Utilize the table variable to insert into third table
insert into dbo.table3(......, name_client, phone_client, client_id)
SELECT .......,name_client, phone_client, tv.clientID from @tableName tv 
--where some condition
```

Comment: this is not going to work as I do not have an inner join from first table to third table. Also your declaration of table variable is missing a type Table. .@Venkataraman.

Comment: Sorry. I have corrected it. I have provided sample approach. As you have not provided any sample data and what you want to achieve, it is just an approach to solve problem